# How to prevent a parent movieclip event from being fired

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, air

I have an AS3 movieclip with a button. Both the movieclip and button needs a click event but when I click the button it also fires the parent movieclip's event handler.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 7):

Add an event listener to the child button and use [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29) to prevent the event from bubbling any further up the display list.

Comment: +1 or alternatively stopPropagation(), which will likely do the exact same thing in this case.